# Modding a single cell power bank

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I got this Chinese single cell power bank that I modded with a higher capacity `18650` cell which works fine. I want to add an another cell in parallel with the other one. Will it still charge? will the two batteries reach the cut-off voltage of the charging module? The `IC` on the board is `MP3401` a pretty common in most of the Chinese power banks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can put Li-ion cells in parallel, and yes they will charge, though they obviously will take longer to charge. There are many considerations (cell capacity, charge state etc) in putting cells either in series or parallel, but with only two cells I doubt many would be of concern to you. There are many 2-4P batteries in the RC community.

The only warning for you is to either fully charge or majority discharge (I always discharge on my Li-ion charger) your cells before connecting them together. Once connected together give them at least 15 mins to stabilize before attempting to charge them as a single unit.

You might read through something like [this](http://liionbms.com/php/wp_parallel_balance.php) or many other good texts related to care and maintenance of RC battery packs to gain more knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, good thing I have this large ceramic resistor to discharge them for voltage equalization.